# Approximation of an integral on a certain limit

Tags: renormalization, integration, approximations

In Peskin & Schroeder - Chapter 6 - the authors make the following approximation when $-q^2\rightarrow\infty$

$$\int_0^1 \!\!d\xi\, \frac{-q^2/2}{-q^2\xi(1-\xi)+m^2} \simeq \frac{1}{2}\int_0d\xi\, \frac{-q^2}{-q^2\xi+m^2} + \begin{pmatrix}\!\text{equal contribution}\!\\ \text{from } \xi\approx 1 \end{pmatrix}.\tag{6.64} $$

It might be silly but I don't 'get' all the steps. It is clear to me that the function goes as $\frac{1}{2\xi(1-\xi)}$ in the $-q^2\rightarrow\infty$ limit and the dominant contributions are then about $\xi=0$ and $\xi=1$, but... I don't see clearly what they did in the right hand side. It doesn't seem like a Taylor expansion, then , what is it?

For context: this is a relevant integral for the analysis of IR divergences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I could conjure up. I don't like it cause of sweeping infinities under the rug so feel free to downvote/not accept.

Let
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{m^2}{-q^2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 d\xi\; \frac{1}{\xi(1-\xi)+\frac{m^2}{-q^2}}.
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
f'\left(\frac{m^2}{-q^2} \right)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi\;\left(\frac{1}{\xi(1-\xi)+\frac{m^2}{-q^2}} \right)^2.
\end{align}
Taylor expanding around $0$ (since large $-q^2$, corresponds to small $\frac{m^2}{-q^2}$)
\begin{align}
f(x)&\approx f(0) + f'(0) x+...\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi\;\frac{1}{\xi (1-\xi)} - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi\;\frac{1}{\xi^2 (1-\xi)^2} \frac{m^2}{-q^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi\;\left(\frac{1}{\xi} +\frac{1}{1-\xi} \right) -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi\;\left(\frac{1}{\xi^2} + \frac{1}{(1-\xi)^2}+\frac{2}{\xi(1-\xi)} \right)\frac{m^2}{-q^2},
\end{align}

where the term $\left( \frac{2}{\xi(1-\xi)}\right)$ is subleading, despite being formally infinite, because  $\frac{1}{\xi^2}>\frac{1}{\xi}$, for $\xi\in(0,1)$. If we ignore this term,  we get the Taylor series for
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi \frac{-q^2}{-q^2\xi +m^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 d\xi \frac{-q^2}{-q^2(1-\xi) +m^2}.$$

In general, comparing the higher order terms of the series, we'd neet to ignore terms in less negative power of $\xi$ to arrive at the result.

Comment: Please go over [this revision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/307202) to ensure its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my workings which starts from (6.62) and higher orders might be easier to be extracted.

$\int^1_0(\frac{m^2-q^2/2}{m^2-q^2\xi(1-\xi)})d\xi$

$=\large{\int^{1/2}_{-1/2}(\frac{m^2-q^2/2}{m^2-q^2(\xi'+\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2}-\xi')})d\xi'}$, with $\xi'=\xi-\frac{1}{2}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2}\int^{1/2}_0\frac{d\xi}{\xi^2-(\frac{1}{4}-m^2/q^2)}}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2}\int^{1/2}_0\frac{d\xi}{\xi^2-(\frac{1}{2}a)^2}}$, where $a=\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a}\int^{1/2}_0 d\xi (\frac{1}{\xi-\frac{1}{2}a}-\frac{1}{\xi+\frac{1}{2}a})}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln \frac{\xi-\frac{1}{2}a}{\xi+\frac{1}{2}a}}|^\frac{1}{2}_0$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln((\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}a}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}a})(\frac{\frac{1}{2}a}{-\frac{1}{2}a}))}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln\frac{a-1}{a+1}}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}+1}}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln\frac{(1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2})-2\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}+1}{\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}}$

$\approx\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln\frac{2+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}-2(1+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4m^2}{-q^2})-\frac{1}{8}(\frac{4m^2}{-q^2})^2+\frac{1}{16}(\frac{4m^2}{-q^2})^3...)}{\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}}$ using $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{16}x^3...$

$\approx\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2a} ln\frac{\frac{1}{4}(\frac{4m^2}{-q^2})^2}{\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}}$

$=\large{\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}} ln\frac{m^2}{-q^2}}$

$=\large{-ln\frac{m^2}{-q^2}}$ as $\frac{2m^2-q^2}{q^2\sqrt{1+\frac{4m^2}{-q^2}}}\approx -1$ for large $-q^2$

$=\large{ln\frac{-q^2}{m^2}}$